# Can I create a tag synonym that can be reviewed by admins who have the privilege to create tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

I just created the tag [mfi](/questions/tagged/mfi), which stands for *Made for iPhone*. Within the Apple Dev world, "MFi" has a specific meaning (see the tag for further information).

Anyway, I'd like to create a synonym tag named [made-for-iphone](/questions/tagged/made-for-iphone). Yes, an admin can do that after reading this post (and I wouldn't mind that at all) but for future reference, I'd like to know if there is a way that I can create synonyms for approval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not much point in creating a synonym before anyone uses it.

That said, the way it generally works is for some (other) question is tagged with the potential synonym, someone realizes that there are tags that mean the same thing, and suggests one to be a synonym of the other.

I *suppose* you could add [made-for-iphone](/questions/tagged/made-for-iphone) on the same questions where you have [mfi](/questions/tagged/mfi), but you'd need to have enough points in the one to make the suggestion in the first place. Since that's almost certainly not true, you'd have to make a [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) here on meta anyway. So, basically, all you've got is what you've already done.

Some moderators, however, might look askance at what you're up to, because basically you're astroturfing synonyms.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was just trying to pre-empt something that could have been a future problem.  I created the tag and I wanted to make sure it was well managed, however, I certainly see the other side of the coin.  I imagine there won't be to many MFi questions, however, I wanted to make the tag because half of the similar questions like mine have answers that basically state "check out the MFi program".  I'm well past that stage but I need further help.  Tagging a question as MFi allows for me (and others) to ask specific questions once we are past the "acceptance into MFi" hurdle.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way for regular users (whatever reputation) to "preemptively" create a synonym like that.

To request a synonym via the normal way (with the [synonym link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mfi/synonyms) on the tag page), you need 2.5k rep and at least an answer score of 5 on the tag. Since `mfi` is new, no users currently have that. You couldn't do it the other way either, [made-for-iphone](/questions/tagged/made-for-iphone) would need to exist first.

Under 2.5k, and with no-one qualifying to suggest a synonym for these tags, your only chance is posting here.